# How do contracts with timing functions get executed?

Tags: mining, evm, validators, timers, timelock

Let's say, there's a contract with timelock or vesting. In it there's a condition that check whether or not the right time has come, in order to release some tokens to some people.  But said condition is getting checked everything second, sometimes every minute.

And there may be millions contracts on Ethereum that have such functionality.

How does these timing or vesting mechanisms work from the point of view of miners and validadators? Does EVM, of each miner or validator, work in such a way that it a) iterates over **all the contracts** on the blockchain, b) **every second**, and, in regards to timing/vestings contracts, if EVM encounters those, it c) executes them?

If so, to me it seems like a very expensive operation.

And if so, is there any low limit of how often something can be executed? Can there a contract with timing of 0.1 second? And would it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work with time, it works with block.timestamp which is a Unix time stamp.

for example at block number XXXXXX, something happens.

Then secondly, it does not automatically execute, its more of a requirement that checks. So a user will have to click to withdraw duns, then the blockchain checks if the time is met, if not...transaction will fail. Otherwise it will work :)

Comment: `for example at block number XXXXXX, something happens.` -- how in Solidity, in code, can that be specified?

Comment: you just call "block.timestamp" and it returns the value

Comment: therefore, a user or admin will have to call a `contract#function(...)` **manually**? Whether it be once a day, or once a minute, right?

Comment: Yes, when the transaction is happening, it calls it

Comment: do you you mean "when the transaction is happening,"? What transaction?

Comment: "it calls it" -- what calls what?

Comment: When a transaction event occurs, the requirement check that calls "bock.timestamp" is called

Comment: what's "a transaction event" ?